# 角【かく】?角【かど】?角【つの】?

Tags: readings, multiple-readings

I found this sentence

「角に大きな目印をつければ、区別しやすくなる」

*He thought, "If we put a big marker on the corner, it will make it easier to distinguish them."*

https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/economy/20220708-OYT1T50101/

j-talk.com gave me this reading:

「かくにおおきなめじるしをつければ、くべつしやすくなる」

Google translate provided this transliteration:

`Tsuno ni ōkina mejirushi o tsukereba, kubetsu shi yasuku naru'

but I think this reading is right:

「角【かど】に大【おお】きな目印【めじるし】をつければ、区別【くべつ】しやすくなる」

Which is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, かど is the only correct reading in this context.

- かく: angle
- つの: (animal) horn
- かど: corner